# Java constructor with instance methods

Tags: java, oop

over here I have some code that is supposed to make a constructor and some getters for my Fraction class. I'm wondering, is it possible to get both parameters in one getter? Because I'm only supposed to use only one method into obtaining both of my results.

Such as "1/2 and 3/5" for example.

```
import java.lang.reflect.*; import java.lang.annotation.*; import java.util.*; import java.time.*; // Please do not change or remove this line.

class Fraction {
    private Integer nominator;
    private Integer denominator;


    public Fraction(Integer nominator, Integer denominator){
        this.nominator = nominator;
        this.denominator = denominator;
    }

    public Integer getNominator() {

        return nominator;
    }

    public Integer getDenominator() {

        return denominator;
    }


}

class Main {


    public static Fraction createFraction(Integer nominator, Integer denominator) {
        return new Fraction(nominator, denominator);
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        final Fraction HALF = createFraction(1, 2);
        final Fraction THREE_FIFTH = createFraction(3, 5);
        System.out.println((HALF));
        System.out.println((THREE_FIFTH));

    }
    public static String toString(Fraction fraction) {
        return fraction.getDenominator() + "/" + fraction.getNominator();
    }

}
```

Comment: Move your `toString()` from `Main` to `Fraction` and then you have what you need. Edit: also, the term is _numerator_, not nominator.

Comment: Your variable name `nominator` makes no sense. Variable names should represent the purpose of the variable, but `nominator` is not something that happens in fractions. You might have intended `numerator`.

Answer (score 1):

create a small class and return it or use an array
for example something like this

```
class Fraction1{
    private int nominator;
    private int denominator;
}
public Fraction1 getDenominator() {
    Fraction1 fr=new Fraction1();
    fr.nominator=this.nominator;
    fr.denominator=this.denominator;
    return fr;
}
```

..............

Answer (score 1):

First of all, great that you don't have setters and your class is functionally immutable--good start!

I would somewhat resist getting the nominator and denominator at all.  You will eventually have to I'm sure, but try to avoid it.

For instance, if you were multiplying two Fractions you would simply have a Fraction.multiply(Fraction) method that returns a new Fraction, no need for getters.  Anything you might want to do to the nominator/denominator you should be able to do inside the Fraction class.

As for if you really NEED to get the values (with one method):

- Return a float (do the division internally)
- return a string (like your toString method, but in the fraction class)
- A string could also look like "7r1" for a value of 15/2.
- you COULD return an array but I don't recommend it, cryptic return values are not awesome.
- I don't recommend a sub-object either, it would have to have two getters so you aren't really solving any problems here, just kicking it down the line.
- I'd consider a getIntegerValue() and getRemainder() but those are two methods--still they are a decent approach.